# MySQL 8.1 Using Multiple Case Statements in an Insert Gives Ambiguous Error 1064 (42000)

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am creating a stored procedure in MySQL 8.1 and have been having issues when doing an insert statement with multiple case statements. I couldn't find any similar issues on here or anywhere else.

The error returned is:
1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 67

So it does not actually say what the issue is. Just where, but I cant find anything in or around those lines.

Here is the full query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_Populate_Tables()
BEGIN
    /* Calendar Load */
    -- Variables Declaration
    SET @StartDate = '2020-01-01';
    SET @EndDate = '2030-12-31';
    SET @PayPeriodStartDate = '2021-12-26';
    SET @PayPeriodEndDate = '2022-01-08';

    -- Populate Calendar Table
    TRUNCATE TABLE Calendar;

    -- Loop to populate Calendar Table
    calendar_loop: WHILE @StartDate <= @EndDate DO
        INSERT INTO Calendar (
            `Date`,
            `Month`,
            `Day`,
            `Year`,
            `Month_Name`,
            `Month_Year`,
            `Month_Year_Sort`,
            `Month_Short`,
            `Month_Short_Year`,
            `Quarter_No`,
            `Quarter_Desc`,
            `Week_Num`,
            `Start_Of_Month`,
            `Start_Of_Week`,
            `End_Of_Week`,
            `Pay_Period`,
            `Pay_Period_Start`,
            `Pay_Period_End`,
            `Pay_Period_Pay_Date`
        )
        VALUES (
            @StartDate,
            EXTRACT(MONTH FROM @StartDate),
            EXTRACT(DAY FROM @StartDate),
            EXTRACT(YEAR FROM @StartDate),
            MONTHNAME(@StartDate),
            CONCAT(MONTHNAME(@StartDate), ' ', EXTRACT(YEAR FROM @StartDate)),
            CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM @StartDate), LPAD(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM @StartDate), 2, '0')),
            LEFT(MONTHNAME(@StartDate), 3),
            CONCAT(LEFT(MONTHNAME(@StartDate), 3), ' ', EXTRACT(YEAR FROM @StartDate)),
            QUARTER(@StartDate),
            CONCAT('Q', QUARTER(@StartDate)),
            WEEK(@StartDate),
            LAST_DAY(@StartDate - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY,
            DATE_SUB(@StartDate, INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(@StartDate) - 1 DAY),
            DATE_ADD(@StartDate, INTERVAL 7 - DAYOFWEEK(@StartDate) DAY),
            CASE
                WHEN LAST_DAY(@StartDate - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY < @PayPeriodStartDate THEN NULL
                ELSE (DATEDIFF(@StartDate, @PayPeriodStartDate) DIV 14) + 1
            END,
            CASE 
                WHEN LAST_DAY(@StartDate - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY < @PayPeriodStartDate THEN NULL
                ELSE DATE_ADD(@PayPeriodStartDate, INTERVAL ((DATEDIFF(@StartDate, @PayPeriodStartDate) DIV 14)) * 14 DAY)
            END,
            CASE 
                WHEN LAST_DAY(@StartDate - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY < @PayPeriodStartDate THEN NULL
                ELSE DATE_ADD(@PayPeriodEndDate, INTERVAL ((DATEDIFF(@StartDate, @PayPeriodStartDate) DIV 14)) * 14 DAY)
            END,
            CASE 
                WHEN LAST_DAY(@StartDate - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY < @PayPeriodStartDate THEN NULL
                ELSE DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(@PayPeriodEndDate, INTERVAL ((DATEDIFF(@StartDate, @PayPeriodStartDate) DIV 14)) * 14 DAY), INTERVAL 6 DAY)
            END
        );
        
        SET @StartDate = @StartDate + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
    END WHILE calendar_loop;


END
```

If I run it using only one of the Case Statements, it works just fine. The below work:

Only Pay_Period

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_Populate_Tables()
BEGIN
    /* Calendar Load */
    -- Variables Declaration
    SET @StartDate = '2020-01-01';
    SET @EndDate = '2030-12-31';
    SET @PayPeriodStartDate = '2021-12-26';
    SET @PayPeriodEndDate = '2022-01-08';

    -- Populate Calendar Table
    TRUNCATE TABLE Calendar;

    -- Loop to populate Calendar Table
    calendar_loop: WHILE @StartDate <= @EndDate DO
        INSERT INTO Calendar (
            `Date`,
            `Month`,
            `Day`,
            `Year`,
            `Month_Name`,
            `Month_Year`,
            `Month_Year_Sort`,
            `Month_Short`,
            `Month_Short_Year`,
            `Quarter_No`,
            `Quarter_Desc`,
            `Week_Num`,
            `Start_Of_Month`,
            `Start_Of_Week`,
            `End_Of_Week`,
            `Pay_Period`
            -- `Pay_Period_Start`,
            -- `Pay_Period_End`,
            -- `Pay_Period_Pay_Date`
        )
        VALUES (
            @StartDate,
            EXTRACT(MONTH FROM @StartDate),
            EXTRACT(DAY FROM @StartDate),
            EXTRACT(YEAR FROM @StartDate),
            MONTHNAME(@StartDate),
            CONCAT(MONTHNAME(@StartDate), ' ', EXTRACT(YEAR FROM @StartDate)),
            CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM @StartDate), LPAD(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM @StartDate), 2, '0')),
            LEFT(MONTHNAME(@StartDate), 3),
            CONCAT(LEFT(MONTHNAME(@StartDate), 3), ' ', EXTRACT(YEAR FROM @StartDate)),
            QUARTER(@StartDate),
            CONCAT('Q', QUARTER(@StartDate)),
            WEEK(@StartDate),
            LAST_DAY(@StartDate - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY,
            DATE_SUB(@StartDate, INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(@StartDate) - 1 DAY),
            DATE_ADD(@StartDate, INTERVAL 7 - DAYOFWEEK(@StartDate) DAY),
            CASE
                WHEN LAST_DAY(@StartDate - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY < @PayPeriodStartDate THEN NULL
                ELSE (DATEDIFF(@StartDate, @PayPeriodStartDate) DIV 14) + 1
            END
            -- CASE 
            --     WHEN LAST_DAY(@StartDate - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY < @PayPeriodStartDate THEN NULL
            --     ELSE DATE_ADD(@PayPeriodStartDate, INTERVAL ((DATEDIFF(@StartDate, @PayPeriodStartDate) DIV 14)) * 14 DAY)
            -- END,
            -- CASE 
            --     WHEN LAST_DAY(@StartDate - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY < @PayPeriodStartDate THEN NULL
            --     ELSE DATE_ADD(@PayPeriodEndDate, INTERVAL ((DATEDIFF(@StartDate, @PayPeriodStartDate) DIV 14)) * 14 DAY)
            -- END,
            -- CASE 
            --     WHEN LAST_DAY(@StartDate - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY < @PayPeriodStartDate THEN NULL
            --     ELSE DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(@PayPeriodEndDate, INTERVAL ((DATEDIFF(@StartDate, @PayPeriodStartDate) DIV 14)) * 14 DAY), INTERVAL 6 DAY)
            -- END
        );
        
        SET @StartDate = @StartDate + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
    END WHILE calendar_loop;


END
```

And this works using the Pay_Period_End column/CASE statement:

```
calendar_loop: WHILE @StartDate <= @EndDate DO
        INSERT INTO Calendar (
            `Date`,
            `Month`,
            `Day`,
            `Year`,
            `Month_Name`,
            `Month_Year`,
            `Month_Year_Sort`,
            `Month_Short`,
            `Month_Short_Year`,
            `Quarter_No`,
            `Quarter_Desc`,
            `Week_Num`,
            `Start_Of_Month`,
            `Start_Of_Week`,
            `End_Of_Week`,
            -- `Pay_Period`,
            -- `Pay_Period_Start`,
            `Pay_Period_End`
            -- `Pay_Period_Pay_Date`
        )
        VALUES (
            @StartDate,
            EXTRACT(MONTH FROM @StartDate),
            EXTRACT(DAY FROM @StartDate),
            EXTRACT(YEAR FROM @StartDate),
            MONTHNAME(@StartDate),
            CONCAT(MONTHNAME(@StartDate), ' ', EXTRACT(YEAR FROM @StartDate)),
            CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM @StartDate), LPAD(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM @StartDate), 2, '0')),
            LEFT(MONTHNAME(@StartDate), 3),
            CONCAT(LEFT(MONTHNAME(@StartDate), 3), ' ', EXTRACT(YEAR FROM @StartDate)),
            QUARTER(@StartDate),
            CONCAT('Q', QUARTER(@StartDate)),
            WEEK(@StartDate),
            LAST_DAY(@StartDate - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY,
            DATE_SUB(@StartDate, INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(@StartDate) - 1 DAY),
            DATE_ADD(@StartDate, INTERVAL 7 - DAYOFWEEK(@StartDate) DAY),
            -- CASE
            --     WHEN LAST_DAY(@StartDate - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY < @PayPeriodStartDate THEN NULL
            --     ELSE (DATEDIFF(@StartDate, @PayPeriodStartDate) DIV 14) + 1
            -- END,
            -- CASE 
            --     WHEN LAST_DAY(@StartDate - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY < @PayPeriodStartDate THEN NULL
            --     ELSE DATE_ADD(@PayPeriodStartDate, INTERVAL ((DATEDIFF(@StartDate, @PayPeriodStartDate) DIV 14)) * 14 DAY)
            -- END,
            CASE 
                WHEN LAST_DAY(@StartDate - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY < @PayPeriodStartDate THEN NULL
                ELSE DATE_ADD(@PayPeriodEndDate, INTERVAL ((DATEDIFF(@StartDate, @PayPeriodStartDate) DIV 14)) * 14 DAY)
            END
            -- CASE 
            --     WHEN LAST_DAY(@StartDate - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY < @PayPeriodStartDate THEN NULL
            --     ELSE DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(@PayPeriodEndDate, INTERVAL ((DATEDIFF(@StartDate, @PayPeriodStartDate) DIV 14)) * 14 DAY), INTERVAL 6 DAY)
            -- END
        );
        
        SET @StartDate = @StartDate + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
    END WHILE calendar_loop;
```

Does anyone know why this would be occurring? Happy to provide more details.

Thank you!

Tried reformatting, different variable names, using @ or no @ before the variables.

When I add a DELIMITER // line it immediately throws an error.

Comment: Considering that mysql v8.1 is still under development, is there any particular reason fo using it?

Comment: @Shadow In this case no, however I was able to get around the issue. It was because I was using Azure Data Studio which I guess does not cooperate as well with MySQL. I added MySQL WorkBench to the docker-compose file and from that i was able to create the SP. I can also execute it in Azure Data Studio, just cant create

Comment: FWIW, I never use GUI tools for MySQL. Every GUI for MySQL I have used is buggy and introduces weird effects like this. I use the `mysql` command-line client, or preferably SQL scripts executed using the command-line client.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

I had to use MySQL workbench or a different SQL editor/DB tool. I was using Azure Data Studio with the MySQL connector which had been working to this point, but I guess there are still some gaps.